# How do I use variables from an outside script (a js file) inside my HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

I have this HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
{% load static %}  
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/bundle.js' %}">
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>title</title>
</head>
<body>
<p id="url"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

And the script file:

```
(async () => {
  ....
  function makeOutput() {
    return 'a url'
  }

  url = makeOutput()
  window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("url").innerHTML=url;
  }
  ....
})()
```

I want to use the url variable in the HTML, but for some reason it isn't letting me save variables the same as as if I were using a script tag with all the code in it.

Any ideas on how to go about this? Thanks

Comment: There's no difference between the behavior of inline scripts and loaded scripts. Check the Network tab in the Dev Tools to see, if your script was loaded.

Comment: I forgot to mention that its inside an async: (async () => { } )()

Comment: `async` doesn't make any difference, unless the function you want to execute is not placed after `await`, and the awaited promise is never fullfilled.

Comment: The problem is caused by a typo. You forgot the end tag for the `<script>` element, so everything that follows it is part of the script, so there is no paragraph with the id `url` in the document.

Comment: You sure, sir? If I add a > to it it gives me an error at src...